# Attribute Error with List of Stock Tickers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, finance

I am a bit confused as to why I am getting attribute error. This error only occurs when when I put a list equal to stock_list. If I print the list then copy and paste I do not get the error/

I have tried to input tech tickers from the top of the code, but I get attribute error when I try, which doesn't happen when I have the list print then copy and paste, which should be the same thing?

```py
file = 'techtickerlist.csv'
with open(file) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    technologyTickers = []
    for row in reader:
        technologyTickers.append(row[0])

def scrape(stock_list, interested, technicals):
    SuggestedStocks = []
    for each_stock in stock_list:
        try:
            technicals = scrape_yahoo(each_stock)
            condition_1 = float(technicals.get('Return on Equity',0).replace('%','').replace('N/A','-100').replace(',','')) > 25
            condition_2 = float(technicals.get('Trailing P/E',0).replace('N/A','0').replace(',','')) < 25
            condition_3 = float(technicals.get('Price/Book',0).replace('N/A','100')) <8
            condition_4 = float(technicals.get('Beta (3Y Monthly)',0).replace('N/A','100')) <1.1
            if condition_1 and condition_2 and condition_3 and condition_4:
                print(each_stock)
                SuggestedStocks.append(each_stock)  
                for ind in interested: 
                    print(ind + ": "+ technicals[ind])         
                print("------")
                time.sleep(1)   
        except ValueError:
                print('Value Error')
                return
                                              # Use delay to avoid getting flagged as bot
    #return technicals
    print(SuggestedStocks)


def main():

    stock_list = technologyTickers
    interested = ['Return on Equity', 'Revenue', 'Quarterly Revenue Growth','Trailing P/E', 'Beta (3Y Monthly)','Price/Book']
    technicals = {}

    tech = scrape(stock_list, interested, technicals)
    print(tech)
```

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: It's unclear from the code you've posted what the `scrape_yahoo()` function you call but didn't include here is doing.

Comment: Its not necessary to the problem. Im not able to share the full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your implementation

> technicals.get('Return on Equity',0)

Method `get` (for type `dict`) will return default value `0` if the key is not present. And by your implemenation all default values have a type `int`. Because they were set as number, not a string (wrapped with quotation signs).

If zero is a correct default value you may omit error with type changing and keep your implemetation.

> technicals.get('Return on Equity', '0')

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want.

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_base = "https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="
tckr = ['SBUX','MSFT','AAPL']
url_list = [url_base + s for s in tckr]

with open('C:\\Users\\Excel\\Downloads\\SO.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    for url in url_list:
        try:
            fpage = requests.get(url)
            fsoup = BeautifulSoup(fpage.content, 'html.parser')

            # write header row
            writer.writerow(map(lambda e : e.text, fsoup.find_all('td', {'class':'snapshot-td2-cp'})))

            # write body row
            writer.writerow(map(lambda e : e.text, fsoup.find_all('td', {'class':'snapshot-td2'})))            
        except HTTPError:
            print("{} - not found".format(url))
```